# Ipython Notebook: use of different cell for one function

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm using ipython notebook. For commenting my function I would like to insert a markdown in the definition of my function. But in the second code cell, it's start like there is non connection with what I write before.

Example:

- Cell 1:
  def my_function(one,two):
  i=0
- Markdown:
  i is use for index
- Cell 2:
  i+=2

First I have an 'IndentationError: unexpected indent' and secondly an 'NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Each cell has to be an executable snippet of Python code. You can either move your markdown documentation above the function or just use normal comments instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each cell in an IPython notebook has to be independant and is runned individually.
When you shift enter into the first cell you actually totally define `my_function` with only a body of one line. `i=0` in your case. Adding code to a function after it has been defined is not possible. This is the same when you enter somethig in (I)Python prompt. You don't define function across multiple query of input.

as for Why the `i` in undefined, is because the scope of `i` is restricted to the function, but this is classical in most programming languages.

So don't think of the IPython notebook as a full text file with markdown, but more as a differents things to be done in each cell, and do them sequentially.